# PHP API With JSON

Tags: php, api, json

I have been trying to call a JSON feed using PHP the code I have used so far is

```
$json = file_get_contents( 'http://football-api.com/api/?Action=standings&APIKey=********' );
$team_data = json_decode($json);

<?php 
echo $team_data->teams[0]->stand_team_name;
echo $team_data->teams[1]->stand_team_name;

echo $team_data->APIRequestsRemaining;

?>
```

However the first 2 echos don't work but the 3rd one does...

A snippet from the API...

```
{
APIVersion: 1,
APIRequestsRemaining: 1000,
DeveloperAuthentication: "TRUE",
teams: [
{
stand_id: "12049092",
stand_competition_id: "1204",
stand_season: "2014/2015",
stand_round: "29",
stand_stage_id: "12041081",
stand_group: "",
stand_country: "England",
stand_team_id: "9092",
stand_team_name: "Chelsea",
stand_status: "same",
stand_recent_form: "DWDWW",
stand_position: "1",
stand_overall_gp: "28",
stand_overall_w: "19",
stand_overall_d: "7",
stand_overall_l: "2",
stand_overall_gs: "58",
stand_overall_ga: "23",
stand_home_gp: "14",
stand_home_w: "11",
stand_home_d: "3",
stand_home_l: "0",
stand_home_gs: "28",
stand_home_ga: "6",
stand_away_gp: "14",
stand_away_w: "8",
stand_away_d: "4",
stand_away_l: "2",
stand_away_gs: "30",
stand_away_ga: "17",
stand_gd: "35",
stand_points: "64",
stand_desc: "Promotion - Champions League (Group Stage)"
},
```

Any ideas why it is not showing up?

Comment: I think $team_data is an array when you use json_decode method, isn't it ? Then try to print $team_data with print_r for example and then try to access with $team_data['team'][0]..

Comment: Is that snippet something you actually received, or a sample from the documentation? Have you tried `print_r($team_data)`?

Comment: I was following this guide - http://webtutsdepot.com/2009/08/31/how-to-read-json-data-with-php/ 

Where exactly would the print_r($team_data) go?

Comment: Anywhere after `$team_data = ..;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request may not return a result for `stand_team_name` because the API you are calling requires a `comp_id` parameter which isn't shown in the API call you indicate you are making.

From the documentation, the API you are calling requires a competition id as shown below:

`http://football-api.com/api/?Action=standings&APIKey=[YOUR_API_KEY]&comp_id=[COMPETITION]`

Documentation: http://football-api.com/documentation/#Standings

Not adding the `comp_id` results in the following error response:

```
{"APIVersion":1,"APIRequestsRemaining":999,"DeveloperAuthentication":"TRUE","Action":"standings","Params":{"Action":"standings","APIKey":"xxxxxx"},"ComputationTime":0.0018100738525391,"IP":"xxxxxx","ERROR":"You have not entered the competition id, please use the parameter comp_id","ServerName":"Football-API","ServerAddress":"http:\/\/football-api.com\/api"}
```

For testing purposes, use `comp_id=1204` as shown in the documentation and try changing your code to the following which works for me:

```
$json = file_get_contents( 'http://football-api.com/api/?Action=standings&APIKey=********&comp_id=1204');
```

Here's a complete example that works for me:

```
<?
    $api_key = 'xxxxxx';

    $json = file_get_contents( 'http://football-api.com/api/?Action=standings&APIKey=' . $api_key .'&comp_id=1204');

    $team_data = json_decode($json);

    print_r($team_data) . "\n";

    echo $team_data->teams[0]->stand_team_name . "\n";
    echo $team_data->APIRequestsRemaining . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: Sorry where I tried to edit out the API key it deleted the competition ID aswell it currently reads as you mentioned above

Comment: I updated the above with the complete code that works for me.  Just change the value of `$api_key` to your api key. The `print_r($team_data)` will show you what you are getting in the response body to verify there are entries to be displayed.

Comment: Thats sorted it! Thanks for your help much appreciated :D